# How to use amazonka presignURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, haskell, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get to grips with the [amazonka](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/) library.  I want to pre-sign a PUT request for S3. Looking at the [example here](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/blob/develop/examples/src/Example/S3.hs), I put together the code below.  It doesn't work when trying to send up a JPEG image from the client side.  AWS complains that the signature is not correct.

My client-side code works with the nodejs aws sdk, so I can only guess that I am configuring things incorrectly here.

```
<Error>
  <Code>
    SignatureDoesNotMatch
  </Code>
  <Message>
    The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
  </Message>
  <CanonicalRequest>
    PUT
    /my-bucket/test.jpg
    X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-
    Credential=[MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY]%2F20171010%2Feu-west-
    1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20171010T084724Z&X-Amz-
    Expires=100000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=expect%3Bhost
    expect:
    host:s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

    expect;host
    UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
 </CanonicalRequest>
...
```

Here's my code:

```
getS3UrlR :: Handler Value
getS3UrlR = do
  y <- getYesod
  let settings = appSettings y

  env <- newEnv $ FromKeys (AccessKey $ encodeUtf8 $ appAwsAccessKey settings) (SecretKey $ encodeUtf8 $ appAwsSecretKey settings)
  ts  <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime

  let b = BucketName $ appS3Bucket settings
      k = ObjectKey "profile-pic-test"
  url <- liftIO $ runResourceT . runAWST env . within Ireland $ presignURL ts 100000 (putObject b k (toBody ("" :: ByteString)))
  return $ toJSON $ decodeUtf8 url
```

How can I go about debugging this?

Note - `putObject` requires a `RqBody` argument, but I don't have one to provide (as the client is going to supply the request body).  So I just supplied an empty string.  Could that be a problem?

Edit - I tried signing a GET request to see if that would work.  It works fine!  But PUT does not. This is the changed line that works fine:

```
url <- liftIO $ runResourceT . runAWST env . within Ireland $ presignURL ts 100000 (getObject b k)
```

Comment: You could check the actual traffic going over the wire and ensure its correctness.

Comment: You redacted the canonical request from the error output.  This is essentially telling you what elements S3 expected you to pass into the signing algorithm.

Comment: I just edited my question to add the canonical request (with the bucket name changed and the access key removed)

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue from Feb which led me to a workround. It seems that `presignURL` is adding an extraneous header to the signed URL. When I rewrite the request to remove the `Expect` header before signing, the resulting URL works with a simple PUT.

My workaround is included in [my comment on the github issue](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/issues/363#issuecomment-347311820).